# Using lambda expression to change values inside a list

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a variable defined as:

```
List<List<A>> mylist;
```

where

```
public class A
{
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a lambda expression that can do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < mylist[i].Count; ++j)
    {
        if(mylist[i][j].b < 10) mylist[i][j].b = 0;
        else mylist[i][j].b = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the granularity of that expression be? The first or the second for loop?

Comment: LINQ is for querying data, not for manipulating it.  You can use a `foreach` rather than a `for` since you don't actually need the indexes, but other than that, there isn't anything to really change.

Comment: @Servy: the OP asks for a lambda expression, not a Linq expression. Although there is some similarity, these are different aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is some discussion about the usability of the [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement, this can perform this task:

```
mylist.ForEach(x => x.Foreach(y => y.b = (y.b < 10) ? 0 : 1));
```

Or unroll it in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(List<A> la in mylist) {
    foreach(A a in la) {
        a.b = (a.b < 10) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

The `(condition) ? val_true : val_false` is the [*ternary operator*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: a couple mistakes fixed: `mylist.ForEach(x => x.ForEach(y => y.b = (y.b < 10) ? 0 : 1));`

Comment: @Cory: just fixed them as you reported them. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your for loop can be converted to this:

```
List<List<A>> mylist = new List<List<A>>();

foreach (var t1 in mylist.SelectMany(t => t))
{
   t1.b = t1.b < 10 ? 0 : 1;
}
```